# How to make node-gyp version match with the node version

Tags: node.js

npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v18.13.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v8.4.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1

this error shows when I was setting environment for my project I have tried multiple commands but didn't work as i have to install mode_modules to run the project

npm install -g node-gyp --force

I have tried this command

Comment: can you show us your package.json file?

Comment: first, did you delete node_modules folder before npm i command ?